# Migrating Cassandra Java Driver for spark DSE 6.8.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I want to upgrade the Cassandra java driver version to 4.134.1.
I am using Spark DSE version 6.8.23, which is using use-java-driver-core-1.9.0.

How can I do the migration of spark DSE 6.8.23 which should compatible to Cassandra java driver 4.13 API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of refactoring required in your application because the OSS Java driver v4 is not binary-compatible with OSS Java driver v3 or DSE Java driver v1.

Follow the steps in the [Upgrade Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/upgrade_guide/) for details of what you need to know to upgrade the driver.

As a side note, [Java driver 4.14.0 includes some important fixes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/changelog/#4-14-0) and [4.14.1 addresses several CVEs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/changelog/#4-14-1) so we recommend that you upgrade to the latest version instead of 4.13. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick Ramirez. I have gone through the doc and migrated all the modules to 4.14.1.
I want to migrate my spark module DSE version 6.8.23 which should compatible to 4.14.1 API. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You should be using the Spark Cassandra connector in DSE which has the Java driver embedded in it. Cheers!

Comment: DSE java driver 1.9 embedded
For example :-
spark com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.RowReader.read()
still using com.datastax.driver.core.Row.
As per the latest (4.14.1) driver doc I want to migrate it to 
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.Row

Comment: What is the end goal you're trying to achieve @SreekanthP?

Comment: I want to migrate Cassandra driver version 4.14.1 in my application.
I want spark DSE version which should support cassandra java driver 4.14.1.
Current DSE version 6.8.23 I am using.